# how to update sublime text2 to the lastest dev build?

Tags: sublimetext

i'm use sublime text2 dev on ubuntu 12.04.

My current version is 2207 build,but the latest version is 2214 on
`http://www.sublimetext.com/dev`

I want to update it.i find this:
`http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/sublime-text-2-ppa-separate-development.html`

But the ppa does not update to the latest version.So i wonder if there a way to manual update or if there is auto installer/updater for this?

I have download the latest tar file .

by the way ,if i update to latest version,my configuration like key bind,plugin package will still work correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i find a shell script [here](https://gist.github.com/1197854),it's work.